# Swift4 Работа с констрейнтами через код используя Extensions

Tags: ios, swift4

Подскажите в чем проблема, есть вот такой Extensions для расширения работы с констрейнтами, но почему то ругается на [image: Ошибка] в первом и во втором кейсах, а так же в default. 
Помогите пожалуйста разобраться!

```
extension NSLayoutConstraint {
static func quadroAspect (on view: UIView) -> NSLayoutConstraint {
    return NSLayoutConstraint.init(item: view, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .width, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
}

static func contraints(withNewVisualFormat vf: String, dict: [String: Any]) -> (NSLayoutConstraint) {
    let separateArray = vf.split(separator: ",")
    switch separateArray.count {
    case 1: return NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "\(separateArray[0])", options: [], metrics: nil, views: dict)
    case 2: return NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "\(separateArray[0])", options: [], metrics: nil, views: dict) + NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "\(separateArray[1])", options: [], metrics: nil, views: dict)
    default: return NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "\(separateArray[0])", options: [], metrics: nil, views: dict)
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Во втором методы ты возвращаешь массив констрейнов в return, а в описании метода ты указал, что возвращаешь что-то странное `(NSLayoutConstraint)`, что в реальности является одним констрейном, а должно быть `[NSLayoutConstraint]`. В ошибке тебе об этом и говориться, что ожидается один констрейн, а возвращается массив. Правильный код будет выглядеть примерно так:

```swift
    static func contraints(withNewVisualFormat vf: String, dict: [String: Any]) -> [NSLayoutConstraint] {
        let separateArray = vf.split(separator: ",")
        switch separateArray.count {
        case 1: return NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "\(separateArray[0])", options: [], metrics: nil, views: dict)
        case 2: return NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "\(separateArray[0])", options: [], metrics: nil, views: dict) + NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "\(separateArray[1])", options: [], metrics: nil, views: dict)
        default: return NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "\(separateArray[0])", options: [], metrics: nil, views: dict)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Я уже себе все глаза сломал ))) Благодарю добрый человек!

Comment: Чтобы люди охотнее отвечали тебе и раньше, надо помечать правильные ответы как принятые.